# Directive and instance of the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I'm currently trying to understand a block of code that i found and there is part which gives me a hard time

I directive is declared that way :

```
(function () {    
  angular
    .module('meanApp')
    .directive('navigation', navigation);

  function navigation () {
    console.log("enters directive");
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: '/common/directives/navigation/navigation.template.html',
      controller: 'navigationCtrl as navvm'
    };
  }
})();
```

The controller:

```
(function () {
  angular
    .module('meanApp')
    .controller('navigationCtrl', navigationCtrl);

  navigationCtrl.$inject = ['$location','authentication'];
  function navigationCtrl($location, authentication) {
    console.log("enters navigation controller")
    var vm = this;

    vm.isLoggedIn = authentication.isLoggedIn();

    vm.currentUser = authentication.currentUser();
  }
})();
```

The view :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-hide="navvm.isLoggedIn"><a href="login">Sign in</a></li>
        <li ng-show="navvm.isLoggedIn"><a href="profile">{{ navvm.currentUser.name }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing i don't understand is the following:
Why do we use a 'nvvm' variable while the instance of the controller we work with in the controller is named 'vm'.
In the view, instead of `navvm.currentUser.name`, i would have chosen to simply use `vm.currentUser.name`

Thanks for helping me to put some light on this detail

Comment: `controller: 'navigationCtrl as vm'` you can rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the directive:

```
controller: 'navigationCtrl as navvm'
```

The `navigationCtrl` can be referred using the `navm` alias in your view, explaining the `navvm.currentUser.name`.

If it bothers you that much, just replace the controller `alias`by:

```
controller: 'navigationCtrl as vm'
```

And use it as you wanted: `vm.currentUser.name`.

Note that this `alias` allows you to bind data to your `controller` using `this` and thus get rid of the `$scope` keyword.

Comment: thank you for that explanation. But...
I don't understand why it works right now if we declare the alias nvvm in the directive but in the controller, it is used as vm...

Comment: @ArnaudAd the alias has two main purposes: use it in the view like you do with `navvm.currentUser.name`. Get rid of the `$scope` keyword in the controller and bind the values that need to be exposed to your view to the `this` instead. You can see, in your controller that you using a var named `vm` that you bind to the this, explaining the `vm.isLoggedIn` & `vm.currentUser` in your controller.

Comment: Well actually , i have accepted your answer without trying ( because i was sure it would work ) but i just tried and it does not work. No error in console... i don't know where the problem comes from

Comment: @ArnaudAd have you updated your view as well ?
        <li ng-hide="vm.isLoggedIn"><a href="login">Sign in</a></li>
        <li ng-show="vm.isLoggedIn"><a href="profile">{{ vm.currentUser.name }}</a></li>

Comment: @ArnaudAd Did you change the controller alias in your directive too ?

Comment: Sorry. It works. My code was OK. But my IDE didn't save the edits on a page... Thank you again !

Comment: @ArnaudAd No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

nvvm is the alias of controller name, so you can use nvvm in place of navigationCtrl.

vm is a variable inside the controller so not accessible from page.